# Powershell: if statement, pick up null in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, null, azure-web-app-service

im trying to script up a way to find webjob errors in array.

Im having troubles picking up null values in an array.
this is what i have so far.

When i run
`az webapp webjob triggered list --name webapp --resource-group resource-group`

i get this and i want my script to pick up the error: null so i work with it.

{
**"error": null,**
"extraInfoUrl": "............",
"historyUrl": "......................",
"id": ".................",
"kind": null,
"latestRun": null,
"location": "Australia Southeast",
"name": "webjobname",
"resourceGroup": "resource-group",
"runCommand": "Webjob.exe",
"schedulerLogsUrl": null,
"settings": {},
"systemData": null,
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/triggeredwebjobs",
"url": "https://........./api/triggeredwebjobs/Webjob",
"usingSdk": false,
"webJobType": null
}

```
  write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $webApp.Name        
        $webjobname = (az webapp webjob triggered list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].name' -o tsv)
        $jobname = ($webjobname -replace ".*/")
        $webjoberror = (az webapp webjob triggered list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].error' -o tsv)

{
            #Count through each of the webjob array
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $webjobname.Count; $i++) 
            {
                #if any of the webjob has a status of stopped    

                if ($null -eq $webjoberror[$i]) 
                {  
                      Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $jobname[$i]
                        Write-Host "No errors with" $jobname[$i] "it looks fine" $webApp.Name $group.ResourceGroupName
                    #Start the Stopped Webjob
               }
                    else
                {      
                       Write-host "There is an error"
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $webjobname[$i]
                    }
                }
}

The error i am getting is Cannot index into a null array.
At line:86 char:21
+                 if ($null -eq $webjoberror[$i]) #latest is null
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:86 char:21
+                 if ($null -eq $webjoberror[$i]) #latest is null
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray


I have tried 
if (!$webjoberror[$i])
if ($webjoberror.count -gt 0)
if ($webjoberror -eq $null)
and different other ones i cant remember. any suggestions?
```

Comment: May I ask why are you not using `ConvertFrom-JSON`?

Comment: ive never thought of it. i can give it a go. im a newbie with scripting. could i ask for your suggestion where to add a convertfrom-json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `az webapp webjob triggered list --name webapp --resource-group resource-group` returns exactly the **JSON** you posted on your answer you can do something like this:

```
$json = az webapp webjob triggered list --name webapp --resource-group resource-group | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Or this would work the same:

```
$resGroup = az webapp webjob triggered list --name webapp --resource-group resource-group
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $resGroup
```

Now you have an object that is pretty easy to maniputale. So for example, if you want to check if `error` is `null`:

```
$json = @'
{
"error": null,
"extraInfoUrl": "............",
"historyUrl": "......................",
"id": ".................",
"kind": null,
"latestRun": null,
"location": "Australia Southeast",
"name": "webjobname",
"resourceGroup": "resource-group",
"runCommand": "Webjob.exe",
"schedulerLogsUrl": null,
"settings": {},
"systemData": null,
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/triggeredwebjobs",
"url": "https://........./api/triggeredwebjobs/Webjob",
"usingSdk": false,
"webJobType": null
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

PS C:\> if(-not $json.error){'Value is Null'}
Value is Null

PS C:\> if($json.error -eq $null){'Value is Null'}
Value is Null
```

The object you get from `ConvertFrom-Json` should look like this:

```
error            : 
extraInfoUrl     : ............
historyUrl       : ......................
id               : .................
kind             : 
latestRun        : 
location         : Australia Southeast
name             : webjobname
resourceGroup    : resource-group
runCommand       : Webjob.exe
schedulerLogsUrl : 
settings         : 
systemData       : 
type             : Microsoft.Web/sites/triggeredwebjobs
url              : https://........./api/triggeredwebjobs/Webjob
usingSdk         : False
webJobType       :
```

Comment: I think i understand how it works. my questions around this is, by doing this, i no longer need to do if (-not $json[$i].error) ? 
In the webapp, i there is multiple webjobs so i find that it just picks the first one and ignores the rest.

Comment: @FranzL supposing you have multiple groups, if you want to find the ones with `error` you can do `$json | where-object {$_.Error}` and if you want to find the ones with null `error` you can do `$json | where-object {-not $_.Error}`

Comment: Thank you @Santiago. Never thought you could do this with powershell. helped me understand a lot from this.

Comment: @FranzL glad to help :) you wouldn't imagine how many things you can do with powershell. If you like it, I definitely recommend practicing every day